# Write text in image inside picturebox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm a noob in MSAccess, but I only need to make aspecific task.

I've a picture (a map) and a PictureBox. I load the map into the picturebox and now I need to write some text in some coordinates inside the map. I can't do it positioning a label because later the image has to be available to be saved with this text.

Could you give me please some Ideas about how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: @JP I've the map in a jpg file.

Comment: What I mean is, if you are generating the map, can't you generate the coordinates and text as well?

Comment: @JP I'm not generating the map. The map is always the same jpg image. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In that case, I can't really be of more help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can only accomplish this by really modifying the image itself.

Positioning a label on top of the map works for you if you print the form or report after you do that. This way you can save it as PDF for example and still have your test on top of the map.

Comment: Agree. As i wrote in the question "I can't do it positioning a label because later the image has to be available to be saved with this text." but I don't know how. :( And later I will need to write the text rotated, so Modifying the image it's the only choice.